# Why the draw rectangle doesn't show in the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried several times running code to display something in the screen but it never shows up anything, it is always a blank screen as you can see:

[image: Blank screen]

I want to draw a rectangle, but why is it not displaying?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

    WHITE=(255,255,255)
    blue=(0,0,255)

    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,blue,(200,150,100,50))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

I'm running Python **3.7.1** and pygame **1.9.4** on macos

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code works fine for me and draws a blue rectangle in a white window. The issue must be related to your system.

Comment: There's been a lot of osx related oddities lately, could you try to move in the `draw.rect()` into the while loop before the update?

Comment: @Rabbid76 It probably is related to my system but if you could give me points to where to look

Comment: @Torxed I tried what you said and it behaved the same way