# Pygame runs without any issues, but nothing is drawn on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to get Pygame to work for a while now. It runs without any issues, but nothing is shown on the screen. 
I did try to run the Pygame alien example game, it does not show up either - even though music starts playing

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (0, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("This is a game!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running is True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type is pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

In the above code I tried filling the screen with the color white, but the window is just blank (the default Mac OS colour)

EDIT:
It seems like it is a problem with Mac OS Mojave

To clarify the code, I tried with red as well as black and white in the end, and nothing shows up

Comment: Seems to be the same like this one:* [Why the draw rectangle doesn't show in the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493449/why-the-draw-rectangle-doesnt-show-in-the-screen)* -still unanswered

Comment: There's been a LOT of OSX related Pygame issues the last couple of weeks. I suggest you submit a bug report on their site and link to these two questions.

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting? The code you've provided just creates a window and fill it with a black color. Although, you named the black color to `white`. That might be what's causing the confusion.

Comment: To elaborate; white is `(255, 255, 255)`, black is `(0, 0, 0)`. You've defined `white = (0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Have you installed Python with Homebrew? Do you have Mojave?

Comment: On Linux I get a black window (see @TedKleinBergman's comment), so the code is OK.

Comment: After a bit of research it seems like Mac OS Mojave is the reason for my headaches! @MykolaZotko Thanks! And yes, Python 3.7 installed with Homebrew. Pygame is installed trough the package manager in Pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555) at GitHub this is a bug of Python installed with Hombrew.

> **UPDATE FIX**: if you download the official macOS x64 installer package of Python 3.7.2 from the official python page and then `pip3 install pygame` it works.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you

Comment: @kaffeDiem You are welcome! Then accept my answer please!

Comment: what if pygame game is running on 2.7 ?